# Using HandleFunc on http vs mux

Tags: go

I'm new to go and want to set up some routing, as well as `cors`. I've been seeing two styles of doing so, one that initializes a multiplexer with `NewServeMux` and then assigns handlers with `HandleFunc`, and one that uses `HandleFunc` directly on `http`. This is what I mean:

```
mux := http.NewServeMux()
mux.HandleFunc("/api", apiFunc)
mux.HandleFunc("/", indexFunc)
```

vs

```
http.HandleFunc("/api", apiFunc)
http.HandleFunc("/", indexFunc)
http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:3001", nil)
```

Are there any differences with these approaches? If they accomplish similar things, is one more common/pragmatic?

Comment: Using your own defined `mux` gives you more flexibility. It would allow you to run multiple services inside the same application. You can't do this using global `mux`, otherwise, different server implementations will overlap and even possibly contradict when using the same pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`http.HandleFunc` et al apply your handlers to a package-global instance of the `ServeMux` held in the `http` package, which `http.ListenAndServe` then starts. You can also create your own instance as you did in the first example, which gives you some more control and makes it easier to unit test. In the end, the choice is yours; the convenience functions and package globals are probably fine for smaller projects with a limited maintenance period, but for larger or longer-lived projects I would generally recommend managing your own instances of both `ServeMux` and `Server`.

Comment: Wonder whether you could even consider using DefaultServeMux as a security flaw. You are hosting routes you potentially don't have full control over. Are there 'best practices' code validators out there that would catch that?

Comment: @ThomasZeman I'm not sure I'd consider that a security flaw; you do have control over it, in that routes are registered by compiled code. No external attacker could maliciously register a route.

Comment: I agree it is a bit contrived, but pulling in arbitrary 3rd party libraries can increase the risk of running malicious code, which registers its handlers.

Comment: @ThomasZeman pulling in arbitrary 3rd party libraries without vetting them is a security risk regardless of whether you're using `DefaultServeMux`.

Answer (score 5):

`http.HandleFunc()` uses `DefaultServeMux` which is a global variable. Therefore any third party package can have access to `DefaultServeMux`. In a scenario in which a third party package was compromised, it could use DefaultServeMux to expose malicious handler to your web application. This is one of the reasons why it is recommended in production code to use your own servemux as shown in your first example.

Comment: Are there any code validators out there catching such potential security flaws?